# replacing word in string that has length of 40 or more

Tags: php, string

I have the following code:

```
$caption = $picture->getCaption();
$words = explode(" ", $caption);
foreach ($words as $word) {
    $string_length = strlen($word);
    if ($string_length > 40) {
        str_replace($word, '', $caption);
        $picture->setCaption($caption);
    }
}
```

However, why doesn't this replace the caption with the trimmed word removed?

Comment: you are replacing but not storing it

Comment: if you deal with non ansi characters, strlen might not be adequate.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the replacement made:

```
$caption = str_replace($word, '', $caption);
```

I think this is much better:

```
$caption = $picture->getCaption();
// explode them by spaces, filter it out
// get all elements thats just inside 40 char limit
// them put them back together again with implode
$caption = implode(' ', array_filter(explode(' ', $caption), function($piece){
    return mb_strlen($piece) <= 40;
}));
$picture->setCaption($caption);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do like this:

```
$caption = $picture->getCaption();
$words = explode(" ", $caption);
foreach ($words as $word)
{
  $string_length = strlen($word);
  if ($string_length > 40) {
       $picture->setCaption(str_replace($word, '', $caption));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it like that :

```
$caption = $picture->getCaption();
$words = explode(" ", $caption);
foreach ($words as $word)
{
  $string_length = strlen($word);
  if ($string_length > 40) {
      $replaced = str_replace($word, '', $caption);
      $picture->setCaption($replaced);
  }
}
```